# Java swing graphics image related questions

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, awt

I am trying to write some programs where I load images to a panel.
Here are my 5 questions:

1> Is there any restriction on what kind(extension) of images can be loaded? I tried to load a .bmp file, it didn't load even after I renamed it with .jpg. However, some other file that were with extensions such as .png or .jpg loaded.

2>Is there a way I can cut an image through java to create a new image. Say, I have a 600x600 pixel image and I want to create a new image by selecting a 200x200 pixel from the middle of the original picture.

3>Is there a way I can resize an image?

4>Can I add an image to a scrollpane?

5> Can I rotate an image by an angle ,say 30 degree?

That's it. A little elaboration with examples will be nice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> **1> Is there any restriction on what kind(extension) of images can be
>   loaded? I tried to load a .bmp file, it didn't load even after I
>   renamed it with .jpg. However, some other file that were with
>   extensions such as .png or .jpg loaded.**

Image I/O has built-in support for `GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP`. Image I/O is also extensible so that developers or administrators can "plug-in" support for additional formats. For example, plug-ins for TIFF and JPEG 2000 are separately available.

Check the [Reading/Loading an image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) tutorial page

> **2>Is there a way I can cut an image through java to create a new
>   image. Say, I have a 600x600 pixel image and I want to create a new
>   image by selecting a 200x200 pixel from the middle of the original
>   picture.**

Two ways. Croping the image using Clipping with Graphics. But faster approach is to use  `BufferedImage.getSubimage(int x, int y, int w, int h)` method.

```
  BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read("image file");
  image = image.getSubimage(50, 50, 200, 200);
```

This will crop an image at location(`x, y) == (50, 50)` and size `200 x 200`.

> **3>Is there a way I can resize an image?**

The discussion about the various approach will take a size of a blog. Read through the [`The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()`](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) article for good insight.

However, a quick approach for example: with `cWidth` and `cHeight`

```
BufferedImage tmpImage = new BufferedImage(cWidth, cHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)tmpImage.getGraphics();
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, cWidth, cHeight, null);
```

There is [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) done by MadProgrammer. It is also better to use external library such as [this](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) which does this works nicely.

> **4>Can I add an image to a scrollpane?**

Direct adding is not suggested. use `JLabel` instead. Or use a custom component and override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` function and draw inside it. There are some working example with these two approach. Generally working with `JLabel` is easier.

[See this question answers. Mine including @MadProgrammer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254027/drawing-an-image-in-jscrollpane-within-scale/20254107#20254107) And The custom painting [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) page.

> **5> Can I rotate an image by an angle ,say 30 degree?**

Yes using the `Graphics2D.rotate(double theta)` function; There are actually much more things you can do with the [Graphics2D API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/). Working examples are shown by MadProgrammer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884480/rotate-an-image-in-java-by-the-specified-angle/14885645#14885645) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779877/rotate-bufferedimage-inside-jpanel/15780090#15780090).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sage. Those will keep me busy for a while. One last question: 5> Can I rotate an image by an angle ,say 30 degree?

Comment: For scaling, you might like to have read through [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928). You might also like to have read through [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

Comment: Image rotation [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884480/rotate-an-image-in-java-by-the-specified-angle/14885645#14885645), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779877/rotate-bufferedimage-inside-jpanel/15780090#15780090)

Comment: @MadProgrammar : Thanks, I will check it out. One last thing . Sage says that .bmp is supported by java, then why does it not load while .png with the same code does?

Comment: I did not use BuffereImage, BTW. I was using ImageIcon. Could that be the reason? Whats the difference between buffered image, image and imageicon? it's all so confusing!

Comment: @MadProgrammer, i have updated the answer to link your posted link in the comment.

Comment: @user3015246, i haven't said that. The builders have said that. :) and i checked that they are telling the truth. I don't know what issue you might be facing

Comment: OK, I tried BufferedImage and now it works!.bmp sure doesn't work with ImageIcon. You need BufferedImage with loads of import statements.

Comment: Anyway, Thanks a lot to both Sage and MadProgrammar. It was helpful and it leaves me with a lot of things to try out. Thanks again.

Comment: once again check the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about): this page also has some nice information ;)

Comment: ImageIcon is a wrapper class between Icon and Image, generally, I stick to using Image or BufferedImage, but you can pass BufferedImage to ImageIcon as BufferedImage extends from Image. BMP has a number of sub formats, not all may be supported, pay attention to any exceptions which are raised as they will typically provided you with more information